# The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, dependency-injection

I use N-Layer Architech and dependency injection.
I also want to list the Department list inside the Employee list.

```
public List<Employee> ListEmployee()
    {
        using (var context = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            return context.Set<Employee>().Include("Department").ToList();
        }
    }
```

or I tried two ways but got the same error.

```
 public IQueryable<Employee> GetQueryableEmployee()
    {
        using (var context = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            return context.Set<Employee>().Include("Department").AsQueryable<Employee>();
        }
    }
```

I created my tables like this.
Department table

```
 public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
 public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
```

and Employee table

```
 public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
```

One-to-Many relationship I created with Fluent Api

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
              .HasRequired<Department>(e => e.Department)
              .WithMany(c => c.Employees)
             .HasForeignKey<int>(e => e.DepartmentID);
```

EmployeeController

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IEmployeeService _employeeService;
    public EmployeeController(IEmployeeService employeeService)
    {
        _employeeService = employeeService;
    }
    
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var employee = _employeeService.ListEmployee();
        return View(employee);
    }
```

and View

```
@model IEnumerable<Test.Entities.Concreate.Employee>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Department.DepartmentName)
    </td>
```

How to show two tables in the same list?
Somewhere I think need to equalize DepartmentID

Comment: Fior `GetQueryableEmployee` you will have this exception. Because you have disposed context which have generated `IQueryable`

Comment: var employee=_employeeService.GetQueryableEmployee is it this way?

Comment: Yes, this usage is wrong. You do not have to create context every time but configure DI, to create instance per request.

Comment: builder.RegisterType<EmployeeManager>().As<IEmployeeService>(); builder.RegisterType<EmployeeDal>().As<IEmployeeDal>();

Comment: I did it this way. how can i configure DI ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 0):

To leverage `IQueryable`, at a minimum the DbContext must be scoped at the outer-most point that the entities will be referenced. This can be managed by dependency injection provided the DbContext is lifetime scoped to the Request, or managed by a Unit of Work pattern. (Where a `using` block scopes a unit of work at the controller level that encompasses the DbContext)

Depending on your IoC container, the context can be scoped to something like `PerRequest`. So for example with Autofac:

```
builder.RegisterType<DatabaseContext>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
```

With Dbcontexts you will probably want to consider configuring the container to use a particular Constructor /w parameters for your connection string etc.

Your Repository (EmployeeService) will declare a dependency for the DbContext to be injected when it itself is provided to your controller.

```
public class EmployeeService
{
    private readonly DatabaseContext _context = null;

    public EmployeeService(DatabaseContext context)
    {
        _context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
    }

     public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployees()
    {
        return _context.Employees.AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

The advantage of this approach for repositories is that your service method is just a wrapper for access to the data. Note that I didn't use `.Include()` for the Department, the callers can do that or project the employees however they want.

So in the controller you can go:

```
 var employeesWithDepartments = EmployeeService.Employees
    .Include(x => x.Department)
    .ToList();
```

Or better, just project the data to what you need which will compose a more streamlined query:

```
var employeeViewModels = EmployeeService.Employees
    .Select(x => new EmployeeViewModel
    {
        Name = x.Name,
        Department = x.Department.Name,
        // ...
    }).ToList();
```

Using this pattern you can centralize "core" business logic in your Repository / Service, so for instance if an employee has an IsActive state that you should always be considering by default:

```
 public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployees(bool includeInactive = false)
{
    var query = context.Employees.AsQueryable();
    if(!includeInactive)
        query = query.Where(x => x.IsActive);
    return query;
}
```

Calling code can further filter data with additional `Where` clauses, perform projections with `Select`, or simply take a `Count` or do an `Any` check without requiring additional methods on the repository / service.

Comment: Solved my Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;  problem to get a list but Couldn't find solution for IQueryable.